# Newbie can't run a basic unitils test

Tags: unitils

I'm trying to run a basic test:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4;

public class SampleUnitilsTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

But I am getting the following stack trace:

```
org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: An exception occured during the loading of core module hibernate with module class name org.unitils.orm.hibernate.HibernateModule
    at org.unitils.core.ModulesLoader.createAndInitializeModules(ModulesLoader.java:154)
    at org.unitils.core.ModulesLoader.loadModules(ModulesLoader.java:121)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils.createModulesRepository(Unitils.java:222)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils.init(Unitils.java:118)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils.init(Unitils.java:105)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils.initSingletonInstance(Unitils.java:74)
    at org.unitils.core.Unitils.getInstance(Unitils.java:52)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.getUnitils(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:214)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.getTestListener(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:204)
    at org.unitils.UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.run(UnitilsJUnit4TestClassRunner.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.unitils.core.UnitilsException: Could not load class with name org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
    at org.unitils.util.ReflectionUtils.getClassWithName(ReflectionUtils.java:482)
    at org.unitils.orm.hibernate.HibernateModule.init(HibernateModule.java:86)
    at org.unitils.core.ModulesLoader.createAndInitializeModules(ModulesLoader.java:151)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.unitils.util.ReflectionUtils.getClassWithName(ReflectionUtils.java:479)
    ... 17 more
```

My POM includes the following:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
        <artifactId>unitils-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If it matters, I'm doing this within Eclipse Helios SR2 JUnit 4 tester.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coincidentally, I was trying to pick up unitils for my db testing as well. I was able to replicate your problem with maven 2.2.1. From my prior working experience with maven and hibernate, and the site documentation, those dependencies *should* be all that you need.

If there is any problem, it probably lies with the pom definitions related to hibernate, and sure enough in the pom for unitils-orm, the following dependencies are set as optional:

```
    <!-- Optional dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.ga</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.ga</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>concurrent</groupId>
        <artifactId>concurrent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.4</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

Adding hibernate-entitymanager did resolve the problem As for whether why that pom is defined as such, any valid reasons would only be known to the developers..